# How do I complete the 'Attention to Detail' achievement?

Tags: achievements, world-of-warcraft

There is an achievement for Scholomance Heroic called 'Attention to Detail'

> **Attention to Detail**
>
> Defeat Jandice Barov without ever eliminating a false image in Scholomance on Heroic Difficulty.

Part way through the fight Jandice splits off into multiple mirror images of herself:

[image: Attention to detail]

How do I know which Jandice I need to attack in order to get this achievement?

Comment: I haven't done the fight before, but previous mirror-image bosses (first one in AQ40, for example) retain their raid marker once they split. So put a skull on her head before she splits and look for it afterwards. If that doesn't work, look for visual effects like Hunter's Mark (the obvious one) or other dots and debuffs. I will test when I hit 90 and post a real answer if nobody has done so by then.

Comment: This one doesn't keep its raid marker, the boss complete despawns as part of the encounter before multiple copies of her reappear, thus clearing all raid markers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The achievement is called "Attention to Detail" which made me believe there must be a difference in their looks... but only if you're paying attention.

I found some [comments over at WoWHead](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=6531/attention-to-detail) that indicate the boss's mirror images are slightly different.  I will copy in some of these comments.

### Option 1: Look closely!

You can look at them and pay close attention:

```
CORRECT ILLUSION
Black headband,
Black hair that goes over her shoulder, 
Black chestpiece
Black shoulders

BAD VARIATIONS INCLUDE
White shoulders
White hair
Short hair
Sapphire-White headband
Ruby-White headband
White Chestpiece
```

### Option 2: Macro/chatbox solution

You can also make a nice macro (or type a script into chat) that will show you the model of the original boss alongside a model of your current target, which should help with quickly identifying the right one:

> First, this one:

```
/run frm = CreateFrame("PlayerModel");frm:SetPoint("BOTTOMRIGHT",nil,"BOTTOMRIGHT",0,100);frm:SetHeight(600);frm:SetWidth(300);frm:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_TARGET_CHANGED");frm:SetScript("OnEvent",function(self,event,...) frm:SetUnit("target") end);
```

> It will show a huge model of your current target at the right of your
>   screen.
>
> Then, target the boss and use that one:

```
/run frm2 = CreateFrame("PlayerModel");frm2:SetPoint("BOTTOMRIGHT",frm,"BOTTOMLEFT",0,0);frm2:SetHeight(600);frm2:SetWidth(300);frm2:SetUnit("target")
```

> It will display the original boss next to your current target.
>
> After that, the achievement should be easy
>
> And to deactivate the model box:

```
/run frm:UnregisterEvent("PLAYER_TARGET_CHANGED");frm:Hide();frm2:Hide()
```